# How can you do paging with NHibernate?

Tags: .net, nhibernate, orm, pagination

For example, I want to populate a gridview control in an ASP.NET web page with only the data necessary for the # of rows displayed. How can NHibernate support this?

Answer (score 113, accepted):

`ICriteria` has a `SetFirstResult(int i)` method, which indicates the index of the first item that you wish to get (basically the first data row in your page).

It also has a `SetMaxResults(int i)` method, which indicates the number of rows you wish to get (i.e., your page size).

For example, this criteria object gets the first 10 results of your data grid:

```
criteria.SetFirstResult(0).SetMaxResults(10);
```

Comment: This is pretty much what the Linq (to NH) syntax would look like anyway - Nice.

Comment: It's important to note that you will need to execute a separate transaction for retrieving the total row count in order to render your pager.

Comment: This performs a SELECT TOP query in SQL Server. Try it with SetFirstResult(1).SetMaxResult(2);

Comment: That's previous comment is using NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2000Dialect not NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2005Dialect

Comment: IQuery has the same functions, so it can be used with HQL as well.

Answer (score 87):

You can also take advantage of the Futures feature in NHibernate to execute the query to get the total record count as well as the actual results in a single query.

**Example**

```
 // Get the total row count in the database.
var rowCount = this.Session.CreateCriteria(typeof(EventLogEntry))
    .Add(Expression.Between("Timestamp", startDate, endDate))
    .SetProjection(Projections.RowCount()).FutureValue<Int32>();

// Get the actual log entries, respecting the paging.
var results = this.Session.CreateCriteria(typeof(EventLogEntry))
    .Add(Expression.Between("Timestamp", startDate, endDate))
    .SetFirstResult(pageIndex * pageSize)
    .SetMaxResults(pageSize)
    .Future<EventLogEntry>();
```

To get the total record count, you do the following:

```
int iRowCount = rowCount.Value;
```

A good discussion of what Futures give you is [here](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/04/27/nhibernate-futures.aspx).

Comment: This is great. Futures works exactly like multicriteria without the syntactical complexity of multicriteria.

Comment: After reading the post about Futures I'm left wondering if I should use Future for all my database queries... What's the drawback? :)

Answer (score 47):

From NHibernate 3 and above, you can use `QueryOver<T>`:

```
var pageRecords = nhSession.QueryOver<TEntity>()
            .Skip((PageNumber - 1) * PageSize)
            .Take(PageSize)
            .List();
```

You may also want to explicitly order your results like this:

```
var pageRecords = nhSession.QueryOver<TEntity>()
            .OrderBy(t => t.AnOrderFieldLikeDate).Desc
            .Skip((PageNumber - 1) * PageSize)
            .Take(PageSize)
            .List();
```

Answer (score 31):

```
public IList<Customer> GetPagedData(int page, int pageSize, out long count)
        {
            try
            {
                var all = new List<Customer>();

                ISession s = NHibernateHttpModule.CurrentSession;
                IList results = s.CreateMultiCriteria()
                                    .Add(s.CreateCriteria(typeof(Customer)).SetFirstResult(page * pageSize).SetMaxResults(pageSize))
                                    .Add(s.CreateCriteria(typeof(Customer)).SetProjection(Projections.RowCountInt64()))
                                    .List();

                foreach (var o in (IList)results[0])
                    all.Add((Customer)o);

                count = (long)((IList)results[1])[0];
                return all;
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { throw new Exception("GetPagedData Customer da hata", ex); }
      }
```

When paging data is there another way to get typed result from MultiCriteria or everyone does the same just like me ?

Thanks

Answer (score 23):

How about using Linq to NHibernate as discussed in [this blog post](http://www.ayende.com/Blog/archive/2007/03/20/Linq-For-NHibernate-Orderring-and-Paging.aspx) by Ayende?

Code Sample:

```
(from c in nwnd.Customers select c.CustomerID)
        .Skip(10).Take(10).ToList();
```

And here is a detailed post by the NHibernate team blog on [Data Access With NHibernate](http://www.nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2008/08/31/data-access-with-nhibernate.aspx) including implementing paging.

Comment: Note linq to Nhibernate is in the contrib package and not included in NHibernate 2.0 release

Answer (score 11):

Most likely in a GridView you will want to show a slice of data plus the total number of rows (rowcount) of the total amount of data that matched your query.

You should use a MultiQuery to send both the Select count(*) query and .SetFirstResult(n).SetMaxResult(m) queries to your database in a single call.

Note the result will be a list that holds 2 lists, one for the data slice and one for the count.

Example:

```
IMultiQuery multiQuery = s.CreateMultiQuery()
    .Add(s.CreateQuery("from Item i where i.Id > ?")
            .SetInt32(0, 50).SetFirstResult(10))
    .Add(s.CreateQuery("select count(*) from Item i where i.Id > ?")
            .SetInt32(0, 50));
IList results = multiQuery.List();
IList items = (IList)results[0];
long count = (long)((IList)results[1])[0];
```

Answer (score 6):

I suggest that you create a specific structure to deal with pagination. Something like (I'm a Java programmer, but that should be easy to map):

```
public class Page {

   private List results;
   private int pageSize;
   private int page;

   public Page(Query query, int page, int pageSize) {

       this.page = page;
       this.pageSize = pageSize;
       results = query.setFirstResult(page * pageSize)
           .setMaxResults(pageSize+1)
           .list();

   }

   public List getNextPage()

   public List getPreviousPage()

   public int getPageCount()

   public int getCurrentPage()

   public void setPageSize()

}
```

I didn't supply an implementation, but you could use the methods suggested by [@Jon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54754/how-can-you-do-paging-with-nhibernate#54777). Here's a [good discussion](http://in.relation.to/Bloggers/PaginationInHibernateAndEJB3) for you to take a look.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to define 2 criterias, you can define one and clone it. 
To clone nHibernate criteria you can  use a simple code:

```
var criteria = ... (your criteria initializations)...;
var countCrit = (ICriteria)criteria.Clone();
```