# Querying NHibernate for paging in a web app

Tags: nhibernate

Given a query for example:

```
from Users u where u.Country = "US"
```

I have a web app with a custom grid.

How do I query NHibernate to bring back a specfic page results
given page size and index???

Malcolm

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/54754/how-can-you-do-paging-with-nhibernate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use SetFirstResult and SetMaxResults on the query or criteria:

```
int pagesize = 10;
int page = 2;
query = session.createQuery("...")
  .SetFirstResult(pagesize * page)
  .SetMaxResults(pagesize);
```