# Getting count with NHibernate + Linq + Future

Tags: linq, nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

I want to do paging with NHibernate when writing a Linq query. It's easy to do something like this:

```
return session.Query<Payment>()
    .OrderByDescending(payment => payment.Created)
    .Skip((page - 1)*pageSize)
    .Take(pageSize)
    .ToArray();
```

But with this I don't get any info about the total number of items. And if I just do a simple .Count(), that will generate a new call to the database.

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54754/how-can-you-do-paging-with-nhibernate/1329082#1329082) which solved it by using future. But it uses Criteria. How can I do this with Linq?

Comment: Use Session.QueryOver instead - it saves intellisense and 'compileability', and there is a SelectCount method. If you need I can provide detail example of using it

Comment: Yes please, QueryOver seems to work well too!

Comment: (I spotted an error in my solution and deleted it to avoid confusion. I'll post the fixed version shortly)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The difficulty with using Futures with LINQ is that operations like Count execute immediately.

As @vandalo found out, `Count()` after `ToFuture()` actually runs the Count in memory, which is bad.

The only way to get the count in a future LINQ query is to use `GroupBy` in an invariant field. A good choice would be something that is already part of your filters (like an "IsActive" property)

Here's an example assuming you have such a property in Payment:

```
//Create base query. Filters should be specified here.
var query = session.Query<Payment>().Where(x => x.IsActive == 1);
//Create a sorted, paged, future query,
//that will execute together with other statements
var futureResults = query.OrderByDescending(payment => payment.Created)
                         .Skip((page - 1) * pageSize)
                         .Take(pageSize)
                         .ToFuture();
//Create a Count future query based on the original one.
//The paged query will be sent to the server in the same roundtrip.
var futureCount = query.GroupBy(x => x.IsActive)
                       .Select(x => x.Count())
                       .ToFutureValue();
//Get the results.
var results = futureResults.ToArray();
var count = futureCount.Value;
```

Of course, the alternative is doing two roundtrips, which is not that bad anyway. You can still reuse the original IQueryable, which is useful when you want to do paging in a higher-level layer:

```
//Create base query. Filters should be specified here.
var query = session.Query<Payment>();
//Create a sorted, paged query,
var pagedQuery = query.OrderByDescending(payment => payment.Created)
                      .Skip((page - 1) * pageSize)
                      .Take(pageSize);
//Get the count from the original query
var count = query.Count();
//Get the results.
var results = pagedQuery.ToArray();
```

**Update** (2011-02-22): I wrote a [blog post](http://sessionfactory.blogspot.com/2011/02/getting-row-count-with-future-linq.html) about this issue and a much better solution.

Comment: the extension method in your blog post is a very nice solution

Answer (score 4):

The following blog post has an implementation of ToFutureValue that works with LINQ.

http://sessionfactory.blogspot.com.br/2011/02/getting-row-count-with-future-linq.html

It has a small error on the following line that must be changed from this.

```
var provider = (NhQueryProvider)source.Provider;
```

To this:

```
var provider = (INhQueryProvider)source.Provider;
```

After apply the change you can use que queries in this way:

```
var query = session.Query<Foo>();
var futureCount = query.ToFutureValue(x => x.Count());
var page = query.Skip(pageIndex * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToFuture();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var query = Session.QueryOver<Payment>()
    .OrderByDescending(payment => payment.Created)
    .Skip((page -1 ) * pageSize)
    .Take(pageSize)
```

This is something I just discovered that the Linq to NH handles just fine, the ToRowCountQuery removes take/skip from the query and does a future row count.

```
var rowCount = query.ToRowCountQuery().FutureValue<int>();

var result = query.Future();

var asArray = result.ToArray();
var count = rowCount.Value();
```

Comment: Works well with SQL Server, but not with SQL Server Compact Edition... :(
System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException : There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 2,Token line offset = 1,Token in error = SELECT ]

Comment: The question specifically asked for a linq solution, not QueryOver.

Comment: Strangely, ToRowCountQuery seems to remove groupings... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8012966/torowcountquery-seems-to-ignore-groupings

Answer (score -6):

Ok, it seems it should be working in your case, but I not tested:

```
return session.QueryOver<Payment>()
  .Skip((page - 1) * pageSize)
  .Take(pageSize)
  .SelectList(r => r.SelectCount(f => f.Id))
  .List<object[]>().First();
```

Test first before upvoting ;)

**UPD:** sorry, as I understand you now, you need to get Count of all items. Then you need to run the query without paging:

```
return session.QueryOver<Payment>()
  .SelectList(r => r.SelectCount(f => f.Id))
  .List<object[]>().First();
```

Comment: Neither of those queries will do what is required. Get the paged set of object + get a count of the total number of objects that meet the criteria.

Comment: I think it is clearly mentioned in the question to use NHibernate + Linq instead of QueryOver.