# NHibernate - dynamic QueryOver parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate

I have an MVC project that I'm trying to setup a nice paging solution for.

I have several tables in SQL Server that have several thousand rows that I would like to be able to page through.  If I don't have any type of filter to apply to the paging, it works great. This is the method I'm using to do that:

```
    public virtual PagedList<T> GetPagedData(int startIndex, int count) {
        var rowCount = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(T)).SetProjection(Projections.RowCount()).FutureValue<Int32>().Value;
        var pageOfItems = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(T)).SetFirstResult(startIndex).SetMaxResults(count).List<T>();
        return new PagedList<T>(pageOfItems, startIndex, count, rowCount);
    }
```

I also want the ability to pass in a query to narrow the results down even further, and return a new paging table.  What I have so far is:

```
    public virtual PagedList<T> GetPagedData<T>(int startIndex, int count, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate) where T : class {
        var rowCount = session.QueryOver<T>().Where(predicate).Select(Projections.RowCount()).FutureValue<Int32>().Value;

        var pageOfItems = session.QueryOver<T>().Where(predicate).Skip(startIndex).Take(count).List<T>();
        return new PagedList<T>(pageOfItems, startIndex, count, rowCount);
    }
```

The call to this would look something like this:

```
networks = mRepository.GetPagedData<Network>(page ?? 1, pageSize, x => x.Name.Contains(q));
```

The problem is, it doesn't like the "Contains" expression.  If I do an exact match, it works fine (x.Name == q), but I don't get the results I'm after.

The exception I'm seeing using "Contains" is:

> Unrecognised method call: System.String:Boolean Contains(System.String)

Does anyone have an idea how to get this to accept an expression like this dynamically?  I have a base repository class that I've put this in, because I'll use the same type of behavior for several other tables.  I could write a separate method for each table, but I would rather do this dynamically if it's possible.

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

QueryOver is not LINQ, and it only accepts a very limited set of expressions.

My suggestion is that you rewrite your method to use LINQ, by replacing `QueryOver` with `Query`. The only problem is that it's harder to do the Count using a future query (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955685/getting-count-with-nhibernate-linq-future/4968746#4968746) for details)

Here's a version without Future:

```
public virtual PagedList<T> GetPagedData<T>(int startIndex, int count,
               Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate) where T : class
{
    var query = session.Query<T>().Where(predicate);
    var rowCount = query.Count();
    var page = query.Skip(startIndex).Take(count).List<T>();
    return new PagedList<T>(pageOfItems, startIndex, count, rowCount);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  This worked perfect.  I'll look into that article for the Future Query usage, but I'd glad to have it working in the meantime.

Answer (score 0):

With the `QueryOver` you have to use the extension method `IsLike`, so `x.Name.IsLike(q, MatchMode.Anywhere)`.