# NHibernate 3.0 search with substring

Tags: nhibernate

I'm making a search with [NHibernate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NHibernate) 3.0 IQueryOver, where I have a keyword for a search. I need to search in a string to see if it is part of the string,

```
Query().Where(e => e.Name.Contains(keyword)).List();
```

But this does not do the job as expected. How should such a search be performed?

Comment: Please include what DB you are using and what exactly is not working as expected (not working at all, Exceptions, results that should or should not be includedm, etc.) As Notoriousxl pointed out, SQL CE does not support this.

Comment: Did you try replacing Contains with 'In'? There are other posts in SO mentioning a similar problem like yours: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5044851/nhibernate-dynamic-queryover-parameter

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I checked the NHibernate source and the `ExpressionProcessor` for the `QueryOver` string like you posted above does not support `Contains`. The operations it supports are IsLike and IsIn. You could either use `IsLike` or if you are keen on Contains, use Linq. For example :

```
(from user in db.Users 
where names.Contains(user.Name)
  select user);
```

or

```
query.Where(person.Name.IsLike("%test%")) //In QueryOver
```

I am guessing that you got an "`Unrecognised method call`" exception.

Comment: exactly for sql server 2008. using NHib 3.0 but found out there now is a 3.1 edition available, so might upgrade, as an empty collection in 3.0 crashes.

Comment: This is the solution for now. It just sad Contains dosen't do the job, as I thought. Is it a bug in NHibernate?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know (at least, for SQL Server, it doesn't seem to work with SQL Server Compact), NHibernate translates that IQueryable into a case insensitive "like '%keywork%'" `where` clause. Did you expect a case sensitive search?