# NHibernate futures in SQL Server Compact Edition

Tags: nhibernate, sql-server-ce

I got some good answers from Diego and genonist about using NHibernate future here:
[Getting count with NHibernate + Linq + Future](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955685/getting-count-with-nhibernate-linq-future)

It works fine in SQL Server. But with SQL Server Compact Edition I get this error:
`System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException : There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 2,Token line offset = 1,Token in error = SELECT ]`

Isn't it possible to use future with SQL Server Compact Edition (4)?

Answer (score 0):

I am look for a solution to this question as well when I found this on the [nhUsers Google Group](http://groups.google.com/group/nhusers/browse_thread/thread/f6c13591f5bcca17#).  not a full solution but certainly in the right direction