# LINQ-to-NHibernate: Cannot use Linq Skip() and Take() with FetchMany

Tags: nhibernate, paging, linq-to-nhibernate, nhibernate-3, nhibernate-projections

I have these entities:

```
public class BlogPost {
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Keyword> Keywords { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<BlogComment> Comments { get; set; }
}

public class BlogComment {
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual BlogPost Post { get; set; }
}

public class Keyword {
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<BlogPost> BlogPosts { get; set; }
}
```

I want to load a paged-list of `BlogPost`s by their `Keyword`s and comments-count. So I try this:

```
var entities = session.Query<BlogPost>()
    .Where(t => t.Published)
    .FetchMany(t => t.Keywords)
    .OrderByDescending(t => t.UpdatedAt)
    .Skip((pageNumber - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize)
    .Select(t => new {
        CommentsCount = t.Comments.Count(),
        Post = t
    })
    .ToList();
```

But the folowing error occurs:

Specified method is not supported.

And when I remove `.Skip((pageNumber - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize)` it works! e.g.

```
var entities = session.Query<BlogPost>()
    .Where(t => t.Published)
    .FetchMany(t => t.Keywords)
    .OrderByDescending(t => t.UpdatedAt)
    // remove the below line
    //.Skip((pageNumber - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize)
    .Select(t => new {
        CommentsCount = t.Comments.Count(),
        Post = t
    })
    .ToList();
```

Have you any idea please to take a number of rows by including `Keyword`s? Thanks for any suggestion.

---

I'm using `NHibernate 3.2 mapping by code`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the nhibernate linq provider isn't fully implemented yet.

You could move the skip / take calls to be *after* the ToList() but then you're going to be filtering on the entire result set rather than querying specifically for the records matching that range.

Alternatively you could use the QueryOver<> api which has proper support for Take and Skip as per this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5073510/493

Comment: Thanks. So how can I load a many to many association by QueryOver? The Fetch method just supports one-to-many and one-to-one association! Can you help to load `post.Keywords` and `post.Comments.Count` please?

Answer (score 1):

This should now be supported in 3.3.3.GA

http://sourceforge.net/p/nhibernate/news/2013/03/nhiberate-333ga-released/